# Finding out if a type implements a generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Let's say I have a type, MyType. I want to do the following:

1. Find out if MyType implements the IList interface, for some T.
2. If the answer to (1) is yes, find out what T is.

It seems like the way to do this is GetInterface(), but that only lets you search by a specific name. Is there a way to search for "all interfaces that are of the form IList" (If possible it woudl also be useful if it worked if the interface was a subinterface of IList.)

Related: [How to determine if a type implements a specific generic interface type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503263/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-a-specific-generic-interface-type)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
// this conditional is necessary if myType can be an interface,
// because an interface doesn't implement itself: for example,
// typeof (IList<int>).GetInterfaces () does not contain IList<int>!
if (myType.IsInterface && myType.IsGenericType && 
    myType.GetGenericTypeDefinition () == typeof (IList<>))
    return myType.GetGenericArguments ()[0] ;

foreach (var i in myType.GetInterfaces ())
    if (i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition () == typeof (IList<>))
        return i.GetGenericArguments ()[0] ;
```

*Edit:* Even if `myType` implements `IDerivedFromList<>` but not directly `IList<>`, `IList<>` will show up in the array returned by `GetInterfaces()`.

**Update:** added a check for the edge case where `myType` is the generic interface in question.

Comment: This handles the case of arrays as well, which is nice. If you want to test for arrays explicitly then use "if (myType.IsArray) return myType.GetElementType();"  (And while this might be faster, I hope none of this is performance-critical!)

Comment: For those like me who were curious about why the .IsInterface is needed: GetGenericTypeDefinition() throws if it is called on a non-generic type.

Comment: The Type.IsGenericType property is not available on netstandard 1.6 and lower (and thus not available on .NET Core 1.0), but you can use TypeInfo.IsGenericType instead: type.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType.

Comment: What if MyType is an open genetic type? Do you still need to call GetGenericTypeDefinitiin? In other words, why does typeof(Dictionary<,>).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IDictionary<,>)) return false?

Comment: Because you can't implement an open generic interface. `Dictionary<,>` implements ``IDictionary<`0, `1>`` where `'0` and `'1` refer to the type parameters of `Dictionary<,>` - look it up in ILDasm or similar.

Answer (score 11):

Using reflection (and some LINQ) you can easily do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetIListTypeParameters(Type type)
{
    // Query.
    return
        from interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces()
        where interfaceType.IsGenericType
        let baseInterface = interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
        where baseInterface == typeof(IList<>)
        select interfaceType.GetGenericArguments().First();
}
```

First, you are getting the interfaces on the type and filtering out only for those that are a generic type.

Then, you get the generic type definition for those interface types, and see if it is the same as `IList<>`.

From there, it's a simple matter of getting the generic arguments for the original interface.

Remember, a type can have multiple `IList<T>` implementations, which is why the `IEnumerable<Type>` is returned.

Comment: If you wrap the return expression in parentheses and add another ".First()" to the end then it returns a Type instead of a length-1 IEnumerable<Type>, which is a little easier to deal with. (Personally I think this is an example of being too clever with LINQ, but maybe that's just me.)

Comment: @yoyo Or, you can just call `First` on the results of this method.  If you return `First` from this method, you're *assuming* one type parameter which is outright *wrong*.

Comment: Good point @casperOne, the OP's MyType could implement IList<Foo> and IList<Bar>. So the question should have been "find the T's" not "find the T". The accepted answer doesn't deal with this either.

Answer (score 4):

```
    public static bool Implements<I>(this Type type) where I : class
    {
         if (!typeof(I).IsInterface)
         {
             throw new ArgumentException("Only interfaces can be 'implemented'.");
         }

         return typeof(I).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Anton Tykhyy's proposal, here is a small Extension Method to check if some type implements a generic interface with one given generic type parameters:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if a type has a generic interface. 
    /// For example 
    ///     mytype.HasGenericInterface(typeof(IList<>), typeof(int)) 
    /// will return TRUE if mytype implements IList<int>
    /// </summary>
    public static bool HasGenericInterface(this Type type, Type interf, Type typeparameter)
    {
        foreach (Type i in type.GetInterfaces())
            if (i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interf)
                if (i.GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeparameter)
                    return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a helper method extension

```
public static bool Implements<I>(this Type type, I @interface) where I : class  
{
    if(((@interface as Type)==null) || !(@interface as Type).IsInterface)
        throw new ArgumentException("Only interfaces can be 'implemented'.");

    return (@interface as Type).IsAssignableFrom(type);
}
```

example usage:

```
var testObject = new Dictionary<int, object>();
result = testObject.GetType().Implements(typeof(IDictionary<int, object>)); // true!
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, this is what you are trying to do. If not, please explain further.

```
public class MyType : ISomeInterface
{
}

MyType o = new MyType();

if(o is ISomeInterface)
 {
 }
```

**edit:** if you change your question, please add the fact that you edited..because now my answer looks like it doesn't belong.

In that case, here is a very large LINQ

```
            var item = typeof(MyType).GetInterfaces()
                            .Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))
                            .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments().First())
                            .FirstOrDefault();

if( item != null )
 //it has a type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Type[] typeArray2 = c.GetInterfaces();
for (int num2 = 0; num2 < typeArray2.Length; num2++)
{
     if (this == typeArray2[num2])
     {
          return true;
     }
}
```

--http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DoesATypeImplementAnInterface.aspx