# How do I put all types implementing a certain generic interface in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Given a particular interface `ITarget<T>` and a particular type `myType`, here's how you would  determine `T` if `myType` implements `ITarget<T>`. (This code snippet is taken from the answer to [**an earlier question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121834/finding-out-if-a-type-implements-a-generic-interface).)

```
foreach (var i in myType.GetInterfaces ())
    if (i.IsGenericType
        && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ITarget<>))
        return i.GetGenericArguments ()[0] ;
```

However, this only checks a *single* type, `myType`. How would I create a *dictionary* of *all* such type parameters, where the key is `T` and the value is `myType`? I think it would look something like this:

```
var searchTarget = typeof(ITarget<>);
var dict = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().[???]
             .Where(t => t.IsGenericType
                    && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == searchTarget)
             .[???];
```

What goes in the blanks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var searchTarget = typeof(ITarget<>);

var dict = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetInterfaces()
                      .Where(i => i.IsGenericType
                          && (i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == searchTarget)
                          && !i.ContainsGenericParameters),
                (t, i) => new { Key = i.GetGenericArguments()[0], Value = t })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Note that if you have multiple classes implementing `ITarget<>` and using the same generic type argument -- for example, `class Foo : ITarget<string>` and `class Bar : ITarget<string>` -- then the `ToDictionary` call will fail with an `ArgumentException` complaining that you can't add the same key twice.

If you do need a one-to-many mapping then you have a couple of options available.

1. Use [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211.aspx) rather than `ToDictionary` to generate a [`Lookup<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx):

   ```
   var dict = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
       .GetTypes()
       .SelectMany(/* ... */)
       .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
   ```
2. If you prefer to work with something like a `Dictionary<K,List<V>>` then you could do this:

   ```
   var dict = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
       .GetTypes()
       .SelectMany(/* ... */)
       .GroupBy(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
       .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
   ```

Comment: Alternate:  `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes(). //etc`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks very much. One question, though: what is the motivation for adding `!i.ContainsGenericParameters`?

Comment: `!i.ContainsGenericParameters` excludes `class C<T> : ITarget<T> { ... }`.

Comment: @Luke: I think the limitation you noted is fine, as I only have one implementer of `T` for any suitable `T` of `ITarget<T>`. Just out of curiosity, though, is it possible to have the `ToDictionary` call create a _list_ of suitable types as its value instead of only a single type?

Comment: @James: You could call `ToLookup` to generate a `Lookup<K,V>` instead, or you could use `GroupBy` and then generate a `Dictionary<K,List<V>>` or something similar. I've updated my answer with a few details.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks Luke! Also, Will: in my particular case I do actually want only the types in my assembly, not all loaded assemblies, but your way is good to know about too.