# How to pass method parameter when expected to be generic interface base type in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

Suppose I have an interface defined as follows:

```
interface IContract
{
    void CommonMethod();
}
```

and then another interface which inherits from this interface defined in the manner of:

```
interface IContract<T> : IContract where T : EventArgs
{
    event EventHandler<T> CommonEvent;
}
```

**My specific question is**, given any instance implementing `IContract`, how could I determine if is also `IContract<T>`, and if so, what the generic type of `IContract<T>` is without hard-coding each known type of `IContract<T>` I might encounter.

Ultimately, I would use this determination in order to make a call of the following pattern:

```
void PerformAction<T>(IContract<T> contract) where T : EventArgs
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Even if this where possible how would you call the generic method when knowing the generic type-param at compile-time only? Are you planning to cast your instance of `IContract` to `IContract<WhatEver>`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes, that is the plan.

Comment: Who's to say it doesn't implement `IContract<T>` for multiple T's? Which implementation should be used? All of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you need an instance of `IContract<T>` you have to use reflection to get the generic type-param first and than call the appropriate method:

```
// results in typeof(EventArgs) or any class deriving from them
Type type = myContract.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Now get the generic type-definiton for `IContract<T>` and get the appropriate method.

```
// assuming that MyType is the type holding PerformAction
Type t = typeof(MyType).MakeGenericType(type); 
var m = t.GetMethod("PerformAction");
```

Alternativly if only the method `PerforAction` is generic instead of `MyType`:

```
// assuming that MyType is the type holding PerformAction
Type t = typeof(MyType); 
var m = t.GetMethod("PerformAction").MakeGenericMethod(type);
```

Now you should be able to invoke the method on an instannce of `IContract`:

```
var result = m.Invoke(myInstance, new[] { myContract } );
```

Where `myInstance` is of type `MyType`.

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of that!  Unfortunately, I would not be able to utilize this as the class which implements the interface is also a Windows control with design-time support.  The generics class declaration (*i.e.*, `class Bar<T>`) is incompatible with the Visual Studio Designer.

Comment: Use of reflection in your subsequent edit looks promising.  I am trying to integrate into a test solution right now.

Comment: Was able to get solution to work using methods described in this answer.  Please see below answer for details/actual implementation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**This is the solution I have used:**

First off, many thanks to @HimBromBeere for providing the basis of this solution.  In essence, what he has posted is the answer, however included here are the pertinent details of how I implemented this architecture.

Given the following interfaces:

```
interface IContract
{
    void CommonMethod();
}

interface IContract<T> : IContract where T : EventArgs
{
    event EventHandler<T> CommonEvent;
}
```

I have a classes, which for all intents and purposes are declared as follows:

```
abstract class BaseControl
{
    protected void SubscribeToContract<Type>(IContract<Type> contract) 
        where Type : EventArgs
    {
        contract.ContractChanged += 
            delegate(object sender, Type e)
            {
                // Calls this method to perform other actions:
                OnContractChanged(e);
            };
    }

    // Called when IContract<>.ContractChanged is raised:
    protected virtual void OnContractChanged(EventArgs e);
}

class SpecialControl : BaseControl, IContract<SpecialEventArgs>
{
    ...

    protected override OnContractChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnContractChanged();
        PerformAction(e);
    }

    ...

    void PerformAction(EventArgs e)
    {
        // We can also now find out if "e" is SpecialEventArgs
        if (e is SpecialEventArgs)
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }

   ...      
}
```

Where the method `SubscribeToContract<Type>()` is a protected member inherited from `BaseControl`.  This allows derived classes to implement their own methods like `PerformAction()` while abstracting away having to worry about dealing with the generic interface stuff (goal).

Within my class there is an `event` which I use the following statement to determine if the argument implements `IContract`, which is the base interface for `IContract<>`:

```
if (e.Control is IContract)
{
    // Gets all the IContract<> interfaces e.Control implements:
    var generics = GetIContractGenerics(e.Control.GetType());

    // There might be multiple IContract<> implementations
    // so therefore we need to check them all, even though in
    // practice there will likely only be a single instance:
    foreach (var generic in generics)
    {
        var method = this.GetType().GetMethod(
            "SubscribeToContract", (BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
        method = method.MakeGenericMethod(generic);
        var result = method.Invoke(this, new[] { e.Control });
    }
}
```

In my case setting `(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)` was required in order to get the `GetMethod()` function to return the `SubscribeToContract<Type>()` method.

Where the method `GetIContractGenerics()` was created using the method described in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121834/finding-out-if-a-type-implements-a-generic-interface):

```
protected static IEnumerable<Type> GetIContractGenerics(Type type)
{
    return
        from implementation in type.GetInterfaces()
        where implementation.IsGenericType
        let definition = implementation.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
        where definition == typeof(IContract<>)
        select implementation.GetGenericArguments().First();
}
```

This `GetIContractGenerics()` static method is stored in `BaseControl` for convenience.

Thats it, everything works!  Thanks everyone for your input!