# How to reflect types that have an interface of generic, and get that type of generic

Tags: linq, generics, types

My 1st objective is to filter the types based on a specific interface with a generic.

My 2nd objective is to obtain the type of the generic parameter itself.

```
public UserService : IUserService, IDisposable, IExportableAs<IUserService>
{
  ...
}
```

I cannot assume the structure of the class, its interfaces (if any at all) or alike.  The only thing I know I am targetting `ExportableAs<T>` from my shared assembly that was used to create this plugin.  But yet, I need to register the type dynamically.

So, I am using a generic interface to mark the type to export.  In this case, it's `IUserService`.  I am doing this assuming some nifty Linq query can give me what I want.  But, I am having a little trouble.

Here's what I have so far:

```
assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => 
                i.IsGenericType &&
                i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IExportableAs<>))
            ).ToList()
    .ForEach(t => _catalogs.Add(
            new ComposablePart()
            {
                Name = t.FullName,
                Type = t // This is incorrect
            })
        );
```

This is working, but notice the comment above for "This is incorrect".  This type is the derived class of `UserService`.

What I need in my end result are:

- The generic type pass into the `IExportableAs<T>` (`IUserService` in this case)
- The derived class type (in this case, `UserService`)

This question got a good up-vote as it got me close (as you can see above): [How to determine if a type implements a specific generic interface type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503263/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-a-specific-generic-interface-type)  But, I need to go one step further in finding that generic type.

Feel free to mangle my linq above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it

```
assembly.GetTypes().SelectMany(t => t.GetInterfaces(), (t, i) => new { t, i })
    .Where(ti => ti.i.IsGenericType &&
                 ti.i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == (typeof(IExportableAs<>)))
    .Select(ti => new ComposablePart() {
        Name = ti.t.FullName,
        Type = ti.i.GetGenericArguments()[0]
    });
```

[Edit] In my excitement, I didn't leave my test program running long enough to throw an Exception on the interface that wasn't generic. Thought the .NET Framework had been especially clever there. Corrected code now that I know it isn't.

Comment: Interesting.  Using an anonymous type to create an object. This has promise. +1

Comment: Yep, that was it. Note though, you are creating a 2nd anonymous type in the Select() clause. It should be: `.Select(ti => new ComposablePart() { Name = ti.t.FullName, Type = ti.i.GetGenericArguments()[0] });` Or else, it will not convert to a known type on a ToList().

Comment: I have a concern with the `GetGenericTypeDefinition()[0]` index though. This limits me to only 1 `IExportableAs<>` correct?

Comment: Sorry about the error; I couldn't be bothered to define ComposablePart in my test app :).  I'll fix that. There is no `GetGenericTypeDefinition()[0]` - there is a `GetGenericArguments()[0]` which limits you only to one type T in each generic type IExportableAs<T>. Easily extended if you need more, but it doesn't make sense. You can have as many IExportableAs<T> on a class as you like.

Comment: Just to clarify: `i.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` simply turns `IExportableAs<T>` into `IExportableAs<>` so that it can be compared.