# Castle Windsor Fluent Configuration: Is it possible to make a specific lifestyle for a given service without using the concrete implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, fluent-interface

I have a collection of services that I want to register with Castle Windsor (version 3.0 RC1) using the fluent registration technique.

I want all of them except for a particular one to use the transient lifestyle and that one I want to be a singleton, so I do this:

```
container.Register(AllTypes
                       .FromThisAssembly()
                       .InSameNamespaceAs<IMyService>()
                       .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()
                       .ConfigureIf(s => s.Implementation == typeof(MyService),
                                    s => s.LifestyleSingleton(),
                                    s => s.LifestyleTransient()));
```

The problem I have with that is that I am using typeof(**MyService**) in the first parameter of ConfigureIf, but I would prefer it if I could use **IMyService** to determine whether it is a singleton or not (i.e. it does not matter what the implementation is, it should always be a singleton).  Is that somehow possible?

Comment: perhaps this could help? [How to determine if a type implements a specific generic interface type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503263/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-a-specific-generic-interface-type)

Comment: perfect thank you!  I changed the first parameter to s => typeof(IMyService).IsAssignableFrom(s.Implementation) and that worked fine.

Comment: Cool, can you post it as an answer and then accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With many thanks to oleksii, who suggested looking at this question: [How to determine if a type implements a specific generic interface type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503263/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-a-specific-generic-interface-type) in the comments on the question, the answer to this is to do the following:

```
container.Register(AllTypes
                   .FromThisAssembly()
                   .InSameNamespaceAs<IMyService>()
                   .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()
                   .ConfigureIf(s => typeof(IMyService).IsAssignableFrom(s.Implementation),
                                s => s.LifestyleSingleton(),
                                s => s.LifestyleTransient()));
```