# Test if class inherits generic interface

Tags: c#, generics

I know there are a few questions on this already but I can't seem to get this to work.

I have a class like this;

```
public class TopLocation<T> : ILocation
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

When I create the class I specify whether it's an `IRestaurant` or `IClub`.  No problem so far.

However, how do I test to see whether it's an `IClub` or `IRestaurant` in an `if` statement?

This fails;

```
if (item.trendItem is ILocation<ITopRestaurant>)
```

and this returns null

```
               Type myInterfaceType = item.trendItem.GetType().GetInterface(
                   typeof(ITopRestaurant).Name);
```

The reason I'd like this in an `if` statement is because it's sitting within an ascx page in an MVC application and I am trying to render the correct partial view.

**edit**

in response to the comment;

```
public interface ITopClub{}
public interface ITopRestaurant { }
public interface ILocation{}
```

Comment: Is there a generic `ILocation` as well? What's the hierarchy? What is `ITopRestaurant`?

Comment: ITopRestaunt is simply an empty interface used to identify the type of ILocation this item is

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503263/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-a-specific-generic-interface-type

Comment: @HackedByChinese, saw that one but looks a little complex for what I thought should be a fairly straight forward thing to do kwim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
if (item.trendItem is TopLocation<IRestaurant>)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `ILocation` is not a Generic Interface so trying to test anything against `ILocation<T>` is going to fail. Your class is the Generic Type.

Second, you're trying to figure out if the type used as a generic argument to your Generic Type is a given interface. To do that, you need to get the Generic Type Arguments for the type and then perform the check against that type:

```
var myInterfaceType = item.trendItem.GetType().GetGenericTypeArguments()[0];

if(myInterfaceType == typeof(ITopRestaurant))
{

}
```