# How to determine if an object implements IDictionary or IList of any type

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say I declare the following

```
Dictionary<string, string> strings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
List<string> moreStrings = new List<string>();

public void DoSomething(object item)
{
   //here i need to know if item is IDictionary of any type or IList of any type.
}
```

I have tried using:

```
item is IDictionary<object, object>
item is IDictionary<dynamic, dynamic>

item.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDictionary<object, object>))
item.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDictionary<dynamic, dynamic>))

item is IList<object>
item is IList<dynamic>

item.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IList<object>))
item.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IList<dynamic>))
```

All of which return false!

So how do i determine that (in this context) item implements IDictionary or IList?

Comment: Take a look at this: [How to determine if a type implements a specific generic interface type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503263/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-a-specific-generic-interface-type)

Comment: @DaveZych, So how do I go about detecting that item implements IDictionary or IList with ANY generic type?

Comment: You are using the `IsAssignableFrom` the wrong way. This is true: `typeof(Dictionary<string, string>).IsAssignableFrom(new Dictionary<string, string>().GetType());`

Comment: May I ask the usage scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the non-generic interface types, or if you really need to know that the collection is generic you can use `typeof` without type arguments.

```
obj.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)
obj.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>)
```

For good measure, you should check `obj.GetType().IsGenericType` to avoid an `InvalidOperationException` for non-generic types.

Comment: `item.GetType() == typeof (IList<>)` is still false, try this

Comment: This would break if the object is a value type like `int/string` since they don't implement the `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` method.

Comment: @dragos Not if one follows the guidance in the answer to check `IsGenericType`.

Answer (score 9):

```
    private void CheckType(object o)
    {
        if (o is IDictionary)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("I implement IDictionary");
        }
        else if (o is IList)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("I implement IList");
        }
    }
```

Comment: it doesnt work: new ExpandoObject() is IDictionary returns false, and he asked if it implements any implementation of  IDictionary<,>

Comment: @elios264 try using IDictionary<string, dynamic> and IList<dynamic> for your checks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you'd want but you could use the `GetInterfaces` on the item type and then see if any of the returned list are `IDictionary` or `IList`

```
item.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.Name == "IDictionary" || x.Name == "IList")
```

That should do it I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some boolean functions that work with generic interface types in vb.net framework 2.0:

```vb
Public Shared Function isList(o as Object) as Boolean
    if o is Nothing then return False
    Dim t as Type = o.GetType()
    if not t.isGenericType then return False
    return (t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().toString() = "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]")
End Function

Public Shared Function isDict(o as Object) as Boolean
    if o is Nothing then return False
    Dim t as Type = o.GetType()
    if not t.isGenericType then return False
    return (t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().toString() = "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue]")
End Function
```