# Checking if my object implements a generic interface in C#

Tags: c#

I have that interface :

```
public interface IEntityWithTypedId<T>{}
```

And have both classes :

```
public abstract class EntityWithTypedId<TId> : IEntityWithTypedId<TId>{...}
public abstract class Entity : EntityWithTypedId<int>{...}
```

So I have entities like those:

```
public class TestA : Entity
public class TestB : EntityWithTypedId<string>
public class TestC : EntityWithTypedId<byte>
```

How can I check if my entities implements IEntityWithTypedId ?

Thanks

Comment: Before I answer, I'd like to fully understand the situation: How would you check if it weren't a generic interface?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if a type implements a specific generic interface type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503263/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-a-specific-generic-interface-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typeof(TestA).GetInterfaces()
    .Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityWithTypedId<>))
```

Comment: No, open generic types are only allowed in a few places, and the is operator isn't one of them