# Generic type casting using Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, generics, activator

I have an interface

```
public interface ISomething<TValue>
    where TValue : IConvertible
{
    ...
}
```

Then I also have some non-generic class with a generic method:

```
public class Provider
{
    public static void RegisterType<TValue>(ISomething<TValue> instance)
        where TValue : IConvertible
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This seems all fine until I want to automatically register all applicable types in my particular assembly.

```
public void InitializeApp()
{
    foreach(Type t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(ISomething<>).IsAssignableFrom(T)))
    {
        // ERROR
        Provider.RegisterType(Activator.CreateInstance(t));
    }
}
```

This code results in error as argument type can't be inferred from usage. I should either

1. provide explicit generic type with my generic method `RegisterType` (I don't think I can do this due to dynamic nature of my code) or
2. cast results from `Activator.CreateInstance` to appropriate type so argument type could be inferred from usage

But I don't know how to do either? Maybe there's a third option I'm not aware of.

Comment: Have you considered invoking `RegisterType` via reflection and `MakeGenericMethod`?  Either that or you sould probably have a non generic `ISomething` and an overload of `RegisterType` that uses that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are a compile-time feature, meaning that the generic types must be known at compile time.  So your `RegisterType` method can't be used when you only know the type at runtime, since there's no way for the compiler to deduce the generic parameter.

You have a couple options here.  You can either use reflection to call the correct version of `RegisterType` (as suggested in the comments), or you can create an additional non-generic overload of `RegisterType` that accepts an object and figures out the execution-time type from that.

For the former, that would look something like this:

```
public void InitializeApp()
{
    foreach(Type t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(ISomething<>).IsAssignableFrom(T)))
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof( Provider ).GetMethod( "RegisterType", BindingFlags.Static );
        var registerTypeMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod( t );
        registerTypeMethod.Invoke( null, new[] { Activator.CreateInstance(t) } );
    }
}
```

Comment: You almost got it right so I'm accepting your answer as the correct one because it led me to solution. For generic type inheritance `IsAssignableForm` won't do the trick when asking about open generic type, because it can't be instantiated. [This answer helped](http://stackoverflow.com/a/503359/75642) in this regard. And also when calling `MakeGenericMethod` we have to provide generic type argument instead of type itself as you did.