# Ensuring a valid IComparer is being used

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, icomparer

I have a class (`Foo`) which is required to compare `T` type objects, however `T` may not always implement IComparable and the constructor should be able to be used with a null `comparer` param. To catch this on creation of `Foo` I attempted the following:

```
public sealed class Foo<T>
{

    private readonly IComparer<T> _comparer;

    public Foo(IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        _comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
        if (_comparer == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException("A comparer was not passed for T and no default was found for T. ");

    }
}
```

I assumed (incorrectly) that `Comparer<T>.Default` would be null if the object did not implement `IComparable<T>` but instead `Default` will still return a valid `Comparer` which throws an `ArgumentsException` when compare is called and I haven't been able to find a solution through research on how to approach this situation.

How should I approach this situation?

EDIT: To clarify This class should be able to sort objects of type T using the given Comparer. But T might not always have IComparable but when a Comparer is provided then it should still be able to sort those objects constraining would break that requirement. However if the passed in Comparer is null then it should attempt to use `Default`, If the object is IComparable all is well if not it should throw an `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: Check MSDN page for Comparer(T).Default: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f(v=vs.110).aspx. Specifically, the remarks mention this: "If type T does not implement the System.IComparable<T> generic interface, this property returns a Comparer<T> that uses the System.IComparable interface."

Comment: Could something like this help in your case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/503359/6741868? Haven't tested it out.

Comment: I made the mistake of not looking at the documentation first. :/ I did see that post on my travels but I wasn't sure it fit with what I was trying to do. Accepted answer seems to be cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your updated question ill give new answer.

```
public Foo(IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    _comparer = comparer ?? 
                     typeof(IComparable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)) 
                     ? Comparer<T>.Default : null;
    if (_comparer == null)
        throw new NotSupportedException("A comparer was not passed for T and no default was found for T. ");

}
```

How ever I don't prefer linear solution. following looks cleaner IMO

```
public Foo(IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    if(comparer == null)
    {
        if(typeof(IComparable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
        {
             comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
        }
        else 
             throw new NotSupportedException("A comparer was not passed for T and no default was found for T. ");
    }

    _comparer = comparer;


}
```

Comment: This has worked like a charm, I'm using .NET-Core and apparently it is a bit more verbose I had to retrieve `TypeInfo` first `(typeof(IComparer<T>).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))` besides that. Fulfills it's purpose perfectly!

Comment: @BarelyTilted I think you got it wrong. you should use **`IComparable<T>`** not `IComparer<T>` :)

Comment: I have indeed! I was excited it was working and didn't double check haha. Though my tests indicate both ways work for what I need.