# Factory that should return different types based on input param

Tags: c#, .net, generics, design-patterns, factory

I have `type` based on which I need to create different objects. The one specific thing - all that object has some common part.

So I thought to have some base class for them. And in each separate class add only specific properties.

```
class BaseClass {
    public int Prop1 {get;set;}
    public string Prop2 {get;set;}
}

class MyClass1 : BaseClass {
    public int PropMyClass1 {get;set;}
}

class MyClass2 : BaseClass {
    public string PropMyClass2 {get;set;}
}
```

I thought about create factories:

```
interface ICreator<T>{
    bool CanHanlde(string type);
    T Create();
}

class Creator1: ICreator<MyClass1>
{
    bool CanHandle(string type) {return "type1" == type;}
    MyClass1 Create();
}

class Creator2: ICreator<MyClass2>
{
    bool CanHandle(string type) {return "type2" == type;}
    MyClass2 Create();   
}
```

And now I would like to create some factory that will return concreate class based on type.
Problem - I don't know how to pass type into generic. From where I need to get type?
I can register all types for `ICreator` and inject it with DI. Select the one which return `true` in `CanHandle` method. But don't know how to get type for generic.

Comment: Is the type only known at runtime? I.e., is the type always given as string?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes well yes, type is value that I query from database

Comment: You can simply use switch like `switch(type) { case "type1": return new MyClass1(); case "type2": return new MyClass2(); }`.

Comment: @shingo do you mean use switch to get type. Then use that type to create concrete creator?

Comment: No, I mean switch the type to create different objects. You already have the type do you?

Comment: You can't really use generics for this - the concrete type for `T` here needs to be resolvable at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

> I can register all types for ICreator and inject it with DI. Select the one which return true in CanHandle method. But don't know how to get type for generic.

Really bizarre question. My understanding is you want to iterate on the available types, call `CanHandle` and return that type if the method returns true. This will require instantiating an instance of each type. Probably this is not what you want, lots of ways for this to go wrong and can't even get compile time checking. But here's how to do this.

First, use reflection to get available types. Then filter the types to the ones that implement the interface. Then instantiate the class. Call "CanHandle" on the class (which the interface says will exist), and if true, you have found your class.

You can separate your classes by assembly/namespace for easier time finding particular classes.

```cs
using SomeNamespace;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class MyClass1 { public int Id { get; set; } }
    public class MyClass2 { public int Id { get; set; } }

    public interface ICreator<T>
    {
        bool CanHandle(string type);
        T Create();
    }

    public class Creator1 : ICreator<MyClass1>
    {
        public Creator1() { }
        public bool CanHandle(string type) { return "type1" == type; }
        public MyClass1 Create() { return new MyClass1(); }
    }

    public class Creator2 : ICreator<MyClass2>
    {
        public Creator2() { }
        public bool CanHandle(string type) { return "type2" == type; }
        public MyClass2 Create() { return new MyClass2(); }
    }
}

namespace SomeOtherNamespace
{ 
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "SomeNamespace")
                .ToList();

            var typeNameToTest = "type2";

            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                if (type.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICreator<>)))
                {
                    // Requires resolving to a matching constructor, the default constructor (no arguments) is implemented above.
                    var newInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    
                    // pick any implementation for nameof...
                    // Probably this can fail if `CanHandle` doesn't exist.
                    var canHandleMethod = type.GetMethod(nameof(Creator1.CanHandle));

                    // This can fail if the signature for `CanHandle` ever changes.
                    bool canHandleResult = (bool)canHandleMethod.Invoke(newInstance, new object[] { typeNameToTest });

                    if (canHandleResult)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Found class that can handle type \"{typeNameToTest}\": {newInstance.GetType().FullName}");

                        break; // or return newInstance
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Found class that can handle type "type2": SomeNamespace.Creator2
```

---

See also [How to determine if a type implements a specific generic interface type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503263/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-a-specific-generic-interface-type) and [How can I get all classes within a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949246/how-can-i-get-all-classes-within-a-namespace).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are querying the types as string from a database, you have a dynamic scenario. I.e., you know the type only at runtime.

Generic types are always resolved at compile time. Therefore, they are not helpful here. Specifically it does not help much to return the concrete type (`MyClass1`, `MyClass2`) from the factory, as you cannot type the variable at runtime. You must use `BaseClass` at compile time.

```cs
 // You don't know whether this will return MyClass1 or MyClass2 at runtime
BaseType result = creator.Create(typeStringFromDb);
```

You can use a type pattern in a switch statement to access the specialized properties:

```cs
BaseType result = creator.Create(typeStringFromDb);
switch (result) {
    case MyClass1 obj1:
        int prop1 = obj1.PropMyClass1;
        ...
        break;

    case MyClass2 obj2:
        string prop2 = obj2.PropMyClass2;
        ...
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

You can still use a generic interface to make it usable with other base types, but you will have to initialize it with a base type.

```cs
interface ICreator<TBase>{
    string Handles { get; }
    TBase Create();
}
```

Instead of having a method `CanHandle` returning a Boolean, I suggest returning the handled type in a string property. This allows you to store the factories in a dictionary and to use this string as key.

I'll do this in a static class with a static constructor to setup the dictionary.

```cs
// Given the classes
class Creator1 : ICreator<BaseClass>
{
    public string Handles => "type1";
    public BaseClass Create() => new MyClass1();
}

class Creator2 : ICreator<BaseClass>
{
    public string Handles => "type2";
    public BaseClass Create() => new MyClass2();
}

// The static creator
static class Creator
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, ICreator<BaseClass>> _creators = new();

    static Creator()
    {
        ICreator<BaseClass> creator1 = new Creator1();
        ICreator<BaseClass> creator2 = new Creator2();
        _creators.Add(creator1.Handles, creator1);
        _creators.Add(creator2.Handles, creator2);
    }

    public static BaseClass Create(string type)
    {
        if (_creators.TryGetValue(type, out var creator)) {
            return creator.Create();
        }
        return null; // Or throw exception.
    }
};
```

Usage

```cs
BaseClass result = Creator.Create("type1");
```

---

**Upate 1, return specific type**

A different variant returns the specialized type but requires a switch statement (or switch expression) to handle the different types. You cannot avoid this, if you want to access the additional members of the derived classes (`PropMyClass1`, `PropMyClass2`).

We declare the interface like this. Note the `out` keyword. It makes the generic types covariant. This allows us add the different creators as `ICreator<object>` to the dictionary.

```cs
interface ICreator<out T>
{
    T Create();
}
```

The Creator factory now uses a dictionary key of type `System.Type`:

```cs
static class Creator
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, ICreator<object>> _creators = new();

    static Creator()
    {
        _creators.Add(typeof(MyClass1), new Creator1());
        _creators.Add(typeof(MyClass2), new Creator2());
    }

    public static T Create<T>()
    {
        if (_creators.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var creator)) {
            return ((ICreator<T>)creator).Create();
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("Non supported type", nameof(T));
    }
};
```

The concrete creators now return the specialied types:

```cs
class Creator1 : ICreator<MyClass1>
{
    public MyClass1 Create() => new MyClass1();
}

class Creator2 : ICreator<MyClass2>
{
    public MyClass2 Create() => new MyClass2();
}
```

Usage:

```cs
switch (typeStringFromDb) {
    case "type1":
        MyClass1 obj1 = Creator.Create<MyClass1>();
        int prop1 = obj1.PropMyClass1;
        //TODO: Do MyClass1 stuff
        break;

    case "type2":
        MyClass2 obj2 = Creator.Create<MyClass2>();
        string prop2 = obj2.PropMyClass2;
        //TODO: Do MyClass2 stuff
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

---

**Update 2, use Polymorphism**

But maybe you should tackle things differently and use [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). To do this, we must formulate the classes in a way that allows us to use the additional properties without having to know the exact class type. This way, we would always work with `BaseClass`.

Now, we implement the base class as abstract class having an abstract method to handle the additional properties

```cs
abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    abstract public void DoStuffWithAdditionalProperty();
}

class MyClass1 : BaseClass
{
    public int PropMyClass1 { get; set; }

    public override void DoStuffWithAdditionalProperty()
    {
        //TODO: use PropMyClass1 here
    }
}

class MyClass2 : BaseClass
{
    public string PropMyClass2 { get; set; }

    public override void DoStuffWithAdditionalProperty()
    {
        //TODO: use PropMyClass2 here
    }
}
```

The creator interface is not generic anymore:

```cs
interface ICreator
{
    string Handles { get; }
    BaseClass Create();
}
```

Implementing the creators and the creator factory is now straight  forward and I will not show it here.

Usage:

```cs
BaseClass result = Creator.Create("type1");
result.DoStuffWithAdditionalProperty();
```

Comment: I got your point, but here `BaseClass result = Creator.Create("type1");` I would like to have `result` as some concrete class (`MyClass1` or `MyClass2`) in order to access some properties that are unique for that types

Comment: I added two solutions. One returning concrete classes and another one using polymorphism. I think using polymorphism is the superior approach as it moves all concrete class specific code that would otherwise be done by the caller to the classes themselves. It also removes the need for switch-statements. Switch statements are often a hint that we should use polymorphism.

Comment: I added a usage example for my first solution.

Answer (score 0):

This would be an easy solution and I hope it helps you:
The class **Creator** should be instantiated only once and with the list of types it could handle.

```
public interface ICreator<T>{
bool CanHanlde(string type);
T Create(string type);
}

public class Creator: ICreator<BaseClass>
{
  List<string> handleTypes;
  public Creator(List<string> supportedTypes)
  {
      this.handleTypes= supportedTypes;
  }

  public bool CanHandle(string type)
  {
      return this.handleTypes?.Contains(type);
  }

  public BaseClass Create(string type)
  {
    switch(type)
    { 
       case "type1": return new MyClass1(); 
       case "type2": return new MyClass2();
    }
    return null;
  }
```