# How can I recognize a generic class?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

How can I recognize (.NET **2**) a generic class?

```
Class A(Of T)
End Class

' not work '
If TypeOf myObject Is A Then
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If c# it would be like this:

```
public class A<T>
{
}

A<int> a = new A<int>();

if (a.GetType().IsGenericType && 
    a.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(A<>))
{
}
```

**UPDATED**:

It looks like this is what you really needed:

```
public static bool IsSubclassOf(Type childType, Type parentType)
{
    bool isParentGeneric = parentType.IsGenericType;

    return IsSubclassOf(childType, parentType, isParentGeneric);
}

private static bool IsSubclassOf(Type childType, Type parentType, bool isParentGeneric)
{
    if (childType == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    childType = isParentGeneric && childType.IsGenericType ? childType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : childType;

    if (childType == parentType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return IsSubclassOf(childType.BaseType, parentType, isParentGeneric);
}
```

And can be used like this:

```
public class A<T>
{
}

public class B : A<int>
{

}

B b = new B();
bool isSubclass = IsSubclassOf(b.GetType(), typeof (A<>)); // returns true;
```

Comment: ?(**new List(of object)**).GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition is gettype(**List(of )**) 
 ***True***

Comment: Throws exception for non generic types: ?(new ArrayList).GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition is gettype(List(of ))
**Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.**

Comment: Yes, it is expected behavior.

Comment: not good. `class B : A(Integer)` this code will not work for B.

Comment: Yes, because B is not a generic type. You can go up through the type hierarchy if you need using type.BaseType() method.

Comment: but I want to detect every instance of A, and every children of A

Comment: not very clear. Need I a special method to detect if myObj is A? If I have C : B : A(T)? or even `Z:Y:X...:C:B:A(T)`?

Comment: ok, very good. Works very well. just fixed some vb.net syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  Public Function IsSubclassOf(ByVal childType As Type, ByVal parentType As Type) As Boolean
    Dim isParentGeneric As Boolean = parentType.IsGenericType

    Return IsSubclassOf(childType, parentType, isParentGeneric)
  End Function

  Private Function IsSubclassOf(ByVal childType As Type, ByVal parentType As Type, ByVal isParentGeneric As Boolean) As Boolean
    If childType Is Nothing Then
      Return False
    End If

    If isParentGeneric AndAlso childType.IsGenericType Then
      childType = childType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
    End If

    If childType Is parentType Then
      Return True
    End If

    Return IsSubclassOf(childType.BaseType, parentType, isParentGeneric)
  End Function
```