# C#, VB.NET type compatibility differences for subclasses of bound version of open type?

Tags: c#, vb.net, types

I am generating code for a VB.NET project, and I've stumbled across something that *should* work, but doesn't.  It appears to point at a discrepancy between C# and VB.NET type compatibility semantics, which is... very unexpected. What am I missing?

```
// C# compiles just fine
public class HasParameters<T>
{
    public void Test()
    {
        if (this is Derived)
        {
            // Do the thing
        }
    }
}

public class Derived : HasParameters<string>
{
}
```

But then, in a shocking twist...

```
' VB.NET complains about apparently equivalent code
' saying "Expression of type 'HasParameters(Of T)' can never be of type 'Derived'"
Public Class HasParameters(Of T)
    Public Sub Test()
        If TypeOf Me Is Derived then
            ' Do the thing
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Derived 
    Inherits HasParameters(Of String)
End Class
```

I haven't been able to find anything that helps me understand the difference between these code samples.

**Obligatory context:** VB.NET doesn't support pattern matching, and I want it.  As part of a larger code generation project, I was trying to generate a function like

```
Public Sub Switch(oneSubclassAction as Action(of OneSubclass), otherSubclassAction as Action(of OtherSubclass))
    If TypeOf Me Is OneSubclass Then 
        oneSubclassAction(DirectCast(Me, OneSubclass))
    ElseIf TypeOf Me is OtherSubclass Then
        otherSubclassAction(DirectCast(Me, OtherSubclass))
    End If
End Sub
```

But that appears not to work in VB.NET if the base class is open and the would-be subclasses derive from bound versions of that type...?  Is there a different way of expressing this in VB.NET that I'm missing?

Comment: For once VB is actually trying to limit bad practice...

Comment: Sure, VB is occasionally opinionated.  And it may be that I have a bad goal in this situation.  But notice the error message isn't along the lines of "TypeOf considered harmful", it's more "these expressions can't be the same type".  That assertion is at odds with what C# thinks unless VB.NET's `TypeOf X is Y` is not actually equivalent to C#'s `X is Y` . There is a factual question to be resolved here regardless of the normative aspects of what I'm doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB typeof operator with generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245719/vb-typeof-operator-with-generics)

Comment: I don't think the C# version "this is derived" can ever be true either - it's just that C# allows you to code this test, while VB doesn't.  The actual behavior of C# "x is" vs VB "TypeOf x Is" is identical.

Comment: You are correct that VB.NET's static checks are pickier (I tried `this is List<string>` before posting, but it was Resharper, not VS itself, that was warning me about it), but `this is Derived` can be true. I've tested it.  VB.NET is claiming at compile time that it can't be true, but we observe C#'s runtime behavior saying that it can be.

Comment: @JerryFederspiel: From your example, I honestly can't see how it *should* be true, but I believe you.