# Eager loading of collection properties during query execution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

Is there a way to eagerly load the child collections of entities fetched in a query without having to specify the paths of the collections as `string`s in the `Expand` method?

Currently I have the following:

```
    foo_entities ctx = new foo_entities(new Uri("http://url/FooService.svc/"));
    ctx.MergeOption = MergeOption.AppendOnly;        
    var things = ctx.Things
                .Expand("ChildCollectionProperty1," +
                        "..." + 
                        "ChildCollectionPropertyN");
    foreach (var item in things)
    {
        foreach (var child in item.ChildCollectionProperty1)
        {
            //do thing
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to avoid putting `string`s in the `.Expand` method, or is reflection my only out to avoid creating copy/paste unchecked by compiler fragility in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only current solution uses reflection to build the `string` or paths for the `.Expand` method.

```
foo_entitiesctx = new foo_entities(new Uri("http://url/FooService.svc/"));
ctx.MergeOption = MergeOption.AppendOnly;

var collections = from pi in typeof(TestResult).GetProperties()
                   where IsSubclassOfRawGenericCollection(pi.PropertyType)
                   select pi.Name;

var things = ctx.Things.Expand(string.Join(",", collections));
foreach (var item in things)
{
    foreach (var child in item.ChildCollectionProperty1)
    {
        //do thing
    }
}
```

(The `IsSubclassOfRawGenericCollection` method is a wrapper around the `IsSubclassOfRawGeneric` method from [Jared Par on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/c-reflection-check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class/457708#457708))