# How do I specify a method that can be accessed only from derived classes of the same assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way in C# to specify a method that can be accessed only from derived classes of the same assembly without using `internal` access modifier?

Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with using internal?

Comment: @Mitch: With `internal` the method is visible everywhere in the assembly.

Comment: @devdept
: and the problem there is?

Comment: @Mitch: `internal` breaks all OOP rules.

Comment: @devdept: the majority of code you see breaks OOP rules. Reflection for instance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [C# Protected Internal](http://kossovsky.net/index.php/2009/06/cshar-protected-internal/)

> **protected**   A protected member is accessible within its class and by
>   derived classes.
>
> **internal**   Internal types or members are accessible only within
>   files in the same assembly.
>
> **protected internal**   Access is limited to the current assembly or
>   types derived from the containing
>   class.
>   * protected internal is the only access modifiers combination allowed
>   for a member or a type.

So you need to use `internal` key word after all:

```
protected internal memberName(){ ... };
```

Comment: But how should we access the base class function from derived class only ?

Comment: @SQL: You have to declare it as `protected` function.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify both internal as well as protected.

Comment: Check this please: http://kossovsky.net/index.php/2009/06/cshar-protected-internal/

Comment: Sorry, I just checked, By typing it Internal Protected. It can be accessed directly from Base Class.         public class Bar
    {
        internal protected void MyFun()
        {
        }
    }                       Bar f = new Bar();
            f.MyFun();

Comment: @Akash Kava: Sorry, that wont solve the problem. Here, access is limited to the current assembly or types derived from the containing class anywhere !!

Comment: Yes but there is no other way, this is the max you can do.

Comment: @devdept, I know what you are saying, but internal means you are the owner and there is no point in restricting yourself in your own project, there is no other way, what are you trying to prove here?

Answer (score 1):

Give the scope of the class as internal
and method scope as protected

```
Internal class Myclass
{
    Protected void MyMethod()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: This way you are limiting the ability to access all the members of `MyClass` to the internal types only !!

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I imagine the situation where you would like to have more flexible control of what assembly class is from, and what class is derived from, than with 'internal' keyword. For example if you wish to check that the object is from th-a-at assembly and derives from one of the-e-e-ese classes.

You can do it through Assembly.GetAssembly() method of the type
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly.aspx

And here is the way to check if object is derived one from another.
[Check if a class is derived from a generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/c-reflection-check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class)

So you can check all you need.

Then you can implement something like:

```
public static bool CheckTypeIsCorrect(Type t)
{
    if(t.GetAssembly().FullName != AssemblyYouNeed) return false;
    if(!(check anything you want in the class)) return false;
    return true;
}
...
public void YourMethod(object value)
{
    if(!CheckTypeIsCorrect(typeof(value))) 
        throw ArgumentException("Type of the object is not correct");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the function `Access modifier` as `Protected` in your **Base Class**. Like below

```
protected void YourFunctionName()
{
//This will be accessible in your derived class only.
}
```

A protected member is accessible from within the class in which it is declared, and from within any class derived from the class that declared this member.

A protected member of a base class is accessible in a derived class only if the access takes place through the derived class type.

Below is an example from **MSDN**

```
namespace SameAssembly
{
    public class A 
    {
       protected void abc()
       {
       }
    }

    private class B : A 
    {
       void F() 
       {
          A a = new A();  
          B b = new B();  
          a.abc();   // Error
          b.abc();   // OK
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not answer the question .. And you need to specify the access modifier of your classes..

Comment: But this way, you still able to access them from the derived classes outside the assembly !

Comment: I think, Other person is concerned only about the function access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like:

```
public class OriginalClass { ... }

internal class DerivedClass: OriginalClass
{
    protected void MemberName() { ... }
}
```

This way, only internal classes can see the `DerivedClass` and only internal derived classes can see the portected members inside it.

And also, you still able to access the `OriginalClass` from everywhere.

Comment: @devdept: This one might fulfill your need.