# C#: Is operator for Generic Types with inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, operators

I have a problem with the is operator comparing generic types.

```
 public interface ISomeInterface<T> where T : SomeBaseClass{
 }

 public class SomeClass : SomeBaseClass{
 }
```

Now we want to check the type with is operator. We have an instance of a class implementing interface ISomeInterface.

Unfortunatly we are facing following problem:

```
 // someObject is an Instance of a class implementing interface ISomeInterface<SomeClass>
 bool isSomeBaseClass = someObject is ISomeInterface<SomeBaseClass>; // false
 bool isSomeClass = someObject is ISomeInterface<SomeClass>; // true
```

Is it possible to check a variable generic type?

Thanks in advance, 
Tobi

Comment: Please clean up your C&P a bit - both of your tests are the same. A declaration for `someObject` would also be good.

Comment: The reason the operator returns `false` is because `ISomeInterface<SomeClass>` is **not** a subtype of `ISomeInterface<SomeBaseClass>`. It's easy to imagine an example where upcasting the first to the second would cause type safety bugs. (For example, casting an `IList<string>` to an `IList<object>`, then adding an integer to it.)

Comment: @millimoose thats exactly the problem. But how can I check it, if i want to get true for a object of IList<string> is IList<object>?

Comment: @Tobias Kek's solution might work for that, but I'm not sure when this would be useful. If the interface isn't covariant over `T`, the two types don't have any meaningful relationship to one another.\

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called generic covariance and is supported in C# 4.0. You could mark the generic `T` parameter with the `out` keyword:

```
public interface ISomeInterface<out T> where T : SomeBaseClass
```

This has a limitation though. The `T` parameter can only appear as return type of the methods in the interface.

Eric Lippert has a [series of blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/default.aspx) on this subject that I invite you to read.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can exploit the covariance and contravariance using the `in` and `out` keyword:

```
public interface ISomeInterface<in T> where T : SomeBaseClass{

}
```

Or:

```
public interface ISomeInterface<out T> where T : SomeBaseClass{

}
```

But remember that using the keyword `in` you can use *T* as a parameter, else using `out` you can use *T* as a return type.

**Covariance:**

A type is covariant when you can convert from `X<S>` to `X<B>`.

**Contravariance:**

A type is contravariant when you can convert from `X<B>` to `X<S>`.

*- where S is the subclass and B the baseclass.*

---

An interesting example that I learn when I was reading my book of C# 4.0 was about the Stack.

```
class Stack<T>{
   int i;
   T[] array = new T[1000];
   public void Push(T element){
       array[i++] = element;
   }
}

class BaseClass{
}

class SubClass : BaseClass{
}
```

Infact it explains that the contravariance could be used in this case, when Stack implements this interface:

```
interface IPushable<in T>{
    void Push(T element);
}
```

Then:

```
IPushable<BaseClass> stackB = new Stack<BaseClass>();
IPushable<SubClass> stackS = stackB;
stackS.Push(new SubClass());
```

While the covariance int this case, when Stack implement the following interface:

```
interface IPoppable<in T>{
    T Pop();
}
```

So then:

```
IPoppable<SubClass> stackS = new Stack<SubClass>();
IPoppable<BaseClass> stackB = stackB;
BaseClass baseClass = stackB.Pop();
```

**This is really helpful because it allows upcasts and downcasts without any problem and Compile-Time errors.**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood your question correctly, but you may need something like answered in [Check if a class is derived from a generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class) :

```
public static bool IsSubclassOfRawGeneric(Type generic, Type toCheck)
{
   while (toCheck != null && toCheck != typeof(object))
   {
      var cur = toCheck.IsGenericType ? toCheck.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : toCheck;
      if (generic == cur)
            return true;
      toCheck = toCheck.BaseType;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer starts with your second question as it seems to show what you are trying to achieve:

**Q: But how can I check it, if i want to get true for a object of `IList<string>` is `IList<object>`?**

Your reasoning seems to be that since string inherits from object, you want a conditional pattern to check for that in generic cases.

```
IList<string> stringList = new List<string>();  
IList<object> objectList = new List<object>();


stringList is IList<string>;
//> true
stringList is IList<object>;
//> false
objectList is IList<string>;
//> false
objectList is IList<object>;
//>true
"someString" is object
//> true
```

Thus you simply check the types of the Generic-Type construct:

along with preceeding boolean checks of `IsGenericType` or `IsGenericConstructedType`, respectively.

```
objectList.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0] is object
//> true
stringList.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0] is object
//> true
```

Caveat: check for null cases; use null coalescing and/or null conditional operators if supported language-wise, etc... It is not in the example for brevity and clarity

---

**Q: Is it possible to check a variable (inherited) generic type?**

In addition to the answers by Darin and fuex, further pointers:

- You can use the IEquality implementation of `Type` for strict type checking:

  ```
  bool condition = (someObject != null 
                    && someObject.GetType().Equals(typeof(ISomeInterface<SomeClass>)) );
  ```
- You check explicitely check for interfaces:

  ```
  var interfaces = someType.GetType().GetInterfaces(); 
  //DotNet4.5: var interfaces = someType.GetType()
  //               .GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces;
  bool condition = (interfaces != null && interfaces.ToList()
                   .Contains(typeof(ISomeInterface<SomeClass>)) == true);
  ```

You can pretty much construct any conditional check with Type and TypeInfo