# Is it possible to recreate this statement without using a foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Is operator for Generic Types with inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186493/c-is-operator-for-generic-types-with-inheritance)

Is it possible to add a list into another list whilst changing class type from Deal to DealBookmarkWrapper without using the foreach statement?

```
var list = new List<IBookmarkWrapper>();
foreach (var deal in deals)
{
    list.Add(new DealBookmarkWrapper(deal));
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the exact equivalent:

```
var list = deals.Select(d => new DealBookmarkWrapper(d))
                .Cast<IBookmarkWrapper>()
                .ToList();
```

But if you're just iterating over the elements and don't really need a `List`, you can leave off the call to `GetList()`.

Comment: `list` will be a `List<DealBookmarkWrapper>` not `List<IBookmarkWrapper>`.

Comment: @JustinNeissner - Justin having some problems with and without the ToList(). Cannot assign method group to implicitly typed local variable

Comment: @user1437135 - Are you sure you included all the appropriate parenthesis?

Comment: @JustinNiessner - definitely Justin, however I've rejigged things a little replcing the IBookmarkWrapper with BookmarkWrapper (a base class) and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

```
var list = deals.Select(d => new DealBookmarkWrapper(d))
                .Cast<IBookmarkWrapper>()
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
 var list = deals.ConvertAll(item=>new DealBookmarkWrapper(item));
```

Answer (score 1):

The question explicitly ask for 'adding a list into another list', so this one could be interesting too:

```
var list = new List<IBookmarkWrapper>();  //already existing
...  
deals.Aggregate(list, (s, c) => 
                      { 
                        s.Add(new DealBookmarkWrapper(c)); 
                        return s; 
                      });
```