# Trying to convert foreach to linq equivalent

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to recreate this statement without using a foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461058/is-it-possible-to-recreate-this-statement-without-using-a-foreach)

I have 2 classes that share a base class

```
DealBookmarkWrapper : BookmarkWrapper
StoreBookmarkWrapper : BookmarkWrapper
```

I also have the following statements:

```
// 1 - This works
List<BookmarkWrapper> bm = new List<BookmarkWrapper>();
foreach(var d in deals)
{
    bm.Add(new DealBookmarkWrapper(d));
}

// 2 - This does not work
List<BookmarkWrapper> bm2 = deals.Select(d => new DealBookmarkWrapper(d)).ToList();
```

1) Works as it but 2 needs a cast to work. I'm unsure whether I'm doing something wrong or if a cast is genuinely required in the second scenario.

Anyone throw some light on it?

Comment: @Nacereddine: This is not a duplicate of that question, the OP wants to know *why* the second solution doesn't work.

Comment: This could help you: [Covariance and Contravariance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186493/c-is-operator-for-generic-types-with-inheritance/11186567#11186567)

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is two-fold:

- The type-argument `T` of `ToList<T>` is inferred by the compiler as `DealBookmarkWrapper`, so a `List<DealBookmarkWrapper`> is produced.
- Since `List<T>` is not a covariant type, no representation-preserving conversion is available from `List<DealBookmarkWrapper`> to `List<BookmarkWrapper>`. For more information on why this is so, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033912/412770).

You've already found out that adding a cast into the `Select` projection is a way around this. Another way, in C# 4 + .NET 4.0 (or later) would be to explicitly specify the type-argument and rely on the covariance of `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
deals.Select(d => new DealBookmarkWrapper(d))
     .ToList<BookmarkWrapper>()
```

Comment: I want to say "nice solution", but that's not enough characters by itself.

Comment: (Nitpick: C# 4 + .NET 2.0 suffice)

Comment: @Timwi: For CLR support maybe, but wasn't the type-parameter of `IEnumerable<T>` marked `out` only in .NET 4.0?

Comment: @Ani: Ooooh good point... I didn’t think of that! Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

```
List<BookmarkWrapper> bm2 = deals.Select(d => new DealBookmarkWrapper(d)).Cast<BookmarkWrapper>().ToList();
```

Or

```
List<BookmarkWrapper> bm2 = deals.Select(d => (BookmarkWrapper)(new DealBookmarkWrapper(d))).ToList();
```

The code you have creates a `List<DealBookmarkWrapper>`, which is not convertible to `List<BookmarkWrapper>`.  The type of the list is determined by C#'s type inference algorithm.

The two options above both create `DealBookmarkWrapper` objects, but cast the reference to `BookmarkWrapper`, so type inference resolves the type as `List<BookmarkWrapper>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. `List<T>` is not [covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832094/covariance-and-ilist) so you need to explicitly cast the objects. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The second scenario needs a cast because your LINQ expression projects into a list of derived objects (`List<DealBookmarkWrapper>`). However, what you want is to create a list of base objects   (`List<BookmarkWrapper>`). Since you want the compiler to "lose" some type information, you need to be explicit about it.

The best solution would be to insert a `Cast<BookmarkWrapper>` before the `.ToList` call, making this explicit and keeping a readable syntax:

```
var bm2 = deals.Select(d => new DealBookmarkWrapper(d))
               .Cast<BookmarkWrapper>()
               .ToList();
```