# How to test if type is some kind of List<>?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if a class is derived from a generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class)

How can I test if a type if some kind of `List<>`? Eg. as the three classes below are.

```
public class Words : List<string>
{
}

public class Numbers : List<double>
{
}

public class BigWords : Words
{
}
```

I tried

```
    typeof(List<DateTime>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(List<>))
    typeof(Words).IsSubclassOf(typeof(List<>))
    typeof(Numbers).IsSubclassOf(typeof(List<>))
    typeof(BigWords).IsSubclassOf(typeof(List<>))
```

But that returned `False` four times. I expected `True` for each.

I expect this question has been answered else where, but I failed to find it, because I found the language of inheritance, polymorphism and generics can be confusing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class/457708#457708

Comment: Thanks @adt I knew this was a hard question! Jared's method works for my four examples.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `Type.IsAssignableFrom` method.