# Check that an object belongs to a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have defined a generic class `MultiSlot<T>`.

At some point I want to check that an object is of this type (i.e. of type `MultiSlot`), but not of a specific type `T`. What I want, basically, is all objects of `MultiSlotl<T>` to enter a certain `if` clause, regardless their specific `T` (given that they all belong to some subclass of `T`).

An indicative (but wrong!) syntax would be: `if (obj is MultiSlot<>)`.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes indeed.. I searched it before I posted (but apparently not enough..). Apologies!

Answer (score 4):

Have a look to 
[Check if a class is derived from a generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class) :

Short answer :

```
    public static bool IsSubclassOfRawGeneric(Type generic, Type toCheck)
    {
        while (toCheck != null && toCheck != typeof(object))
        {

            var cur = toCheck.IsGenericType ? toCheck.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : toCheck;
            if (generic == cur)
                return true;
            toCheck = toCheck.BaseType;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: please [cite](http://stackoverflow.com/a/457708/201088) the other answer when you copy/paste.

Comment: you are absolutely right @Eren Ersönmez... sorry, mistake corrected. I just didn't know how to find it again... and well, I should have truted  StackOverflow search engine! My apologies

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx) method, like this:

```
public bool IsMultiSlot(object entity)
{
  Type type = entity.GetType();
  if (!type.IsGenericType)
    return false;
  if (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MultiSlot<>))
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

and you could use it like:

```
var listOfPotentialMultiSlots = ...;
var multiSlots = listOfPotentialMultiSlots.Where(e => e.IsMultiSlot());
```

Note that this will return `false` for an instance of a subclass (i.e. `StringMultiSlot : MultiSlot<string>`)

Comment: I suppose that the "while" loop addition (in the first answer) make the code work for subclasses. Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

A not so sophisticated approach:

```
var type = obj.GetType();
var isMultiSlot = type.IsGenericType && 
                  type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (MultiSlot<>);
```

This won't work for types inherited from `MultiSlot<T>`, though.

Comment: I suppose that the "while" loop addition (in previous answer) make the code work for inherited types. Thnx!

Comment: Yes the version in the other post is better.