# How to Identify If Object Is Of A Base Generic Type?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a class.

```
DataMapper<TDalType, TFieldType> : DataMapperBase
```

For a particular entity, I have a

```
ObjectADataMapper<TFieldType> : DataMapper<ObjectADal, TFieldType>
```

I then have an instance of a DataMapperBase and need to determine if it is an entity that is a version of ObjectADataMapper (with any value of TFieldType).

Comment: What if you have `DerivedObjectADataMapper<T> : ObjectADataMapper<T>`, would you still want this to be picked up or only direct instances of `ObjectADataMapper`?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - I don't believe there should be an additional level of derivation, however any level of derivation should work probably.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a class is derived from a generic class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class)

Comment: I've voted to close this as duplicate of something else I had found earlier and was unsure how to use.  I was missing the fact that I could do something like "typeof(ObjectADataMapper<>)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check this by seeing if the object's type is generic and if the corresponding generic template is the generic template that you are looking for.  For example:

```
var type = obj.GetType();
bool isObjectADataMapper = type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObjectADataMapper<>);
```

Or, in a reusable way

```
  bool IsInstanceOfGenericTypeClosingTemplate(object obj, Type genericTypeDefinition){ 
      if(obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
      if(genericTypeDefinition== null) throw new ArgumentNullException("genericTypeDefinition");
      if(!genericTypeDefinition.IsGenericTypeDefinition) throw new ArgumentException("Must be a generic type definition.", "genericTypeDefinition");
      Type type = obj.GetType(); 
      return type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericTypeDefinition;
  }
```

You could even take this further and see if the type is derived from the generic type definition in question.  For example, consider that you have:

```
  public class StringDataMapper : ObjectADataMapper<string>
  { 
     // .... whatever
  }
```

In this case the method I provided would fail.  So you'd have to do something like

```
  bool IsInstanceOfGenericTypeClosingTemplateOrSubclassThereof(object obj, Type genericTypeDefinition){ 
      if(obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
      if(genericTypeDefinition== null) throw new ArgumentNullException("genericTypeDefinition");
      if(!genericTypeDefinition.IsGenericTypeDefinition) throw new ArgumentException("Must be a generic type definition.", "genericTypeDefinition");

      Type type = obj.GetType();
      while ( type != typeof(object) )
      {
         if(type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericTypeDefinition) 
         {
            return true;
         }
         type = type.BaseType;
      } 
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, the "clever" way is to use an abstract non-generic base with an `internal` ctor, and only let the generic type definition in question inherit from it.  Then you can do `is ObjectADataMapperBase`, and know safely that any concrete type must implement the generic `ObjectADataMapper<>`.  Alternatively, you could use metadata (e.g. use an `internal` attribute, decorate the generic type definition with that attribute, and write a public extension method that tells whether the type has that attribute.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to get an instance of the type like so:

```
var typeToTestFor = typeof(ObjectADataMapper<>);
```

and a generic type for the object being tested

```
var typeOfObject being tested = objectBeingTested.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();
```

together you can do the following

```
public bool IsObjectADataMapper(DataMapperBase base) {
  var typeUnderTest = base.GetType();
  if (!typeUnderTest.IsGenericType())
    return false; // its not generic so it can't match
  var typeToTestFor = typeof(ObjectADataMapper<>);
  return typeToTestFor.Equals(typeUnderTest.GetGenericTyepDefinition());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `is`

```
if(obj is DataMapper)
{

}
```

Comment: That won't work because I need to know if it is a version of ObjectADataMapper, not any DataMapper.  It could be an ObjectBDataMapper or an ObjectCDataMapper (or any other object) in which case the check should fail.