# Understanding this function that returns Type object

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, reflection, types

I got a cool method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15360480/661933) to check if a type is derived from another. While I was refactoring the code I got this chunk `GetBlah`.

```
public static bool IsOf(this Type child, Type parent)
{
    var currentChild = child.GetBlah(parent);

    while (currentChild != typeof(object))
    {
        if (parent == currentChild)
            return true;

        if(currentChild.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.GetBlah(parent) == parent))
            return true;

        if (currentChild.BaseType == null)
            return false;

        currentChild = currentChild.BaseType.GetBlah(parent);
    }

    return false;
}

static Type GetBlah(this Type child, Type parent)
{
    return child.IsGenericType && parent.IsGenericTypeDefinition 
         ? child.GetGenericTypeDefinition() 
         : child;
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding what `GetBlah` does and hence can't give it a proper name. I mean I can understand the ternary expression as such and `GetGenericTypeDefinition` function, but I dont seem to get its use in the `IsOf` method, especially the `parent` argument that is being passed. Can someone elucidate what actually the `GetBlah` method is returning?

Bonus: Suggest me an apt name for the method :)

Comment: It looks like, if both child and parent are generics but of different types (`List<String>` vs `List<int>` for example) the method is intended to make the same generic type (`List<>`) so they can be compared more correctly.

Comment: and what is now the difference to the `Type.IsAssignableFrom` method?!

Comment: I already answered your question about the GetBlah-method, but what are your trying to do? There is already a `Type.IsAssignableFrom` method. Do you also want to know if `List<int>` is derived from `List<>`? If you need help with that, post a second question (and give me a comment with the new link!) :)

Comment: @Patashu that sounds like the correct answer, can you make it an answer?

Comment: @user287107 difference from what? `IsOf` method? or `GetBlah` method?

Comment: @MartinMulder Indeed, that's what the function does. So no need of posting another question :)

Answer (score 3):

Generic types are like `List<int>` or `List<string>`. They all make use of the same generic type definition: `List<>`.

`IsGenericType` will return `true` is the type is a generic type.
If the type is a generic type definition `IsGenericTypeDefinition` should return true.
The function `GetGenericTypeDefinition` will return the generic type definition of a generic type.

So, if you would do:

```
typeof(List<int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition();
```

You would get `typeof(List<>)`.

So far the theory!

If a analyse your code correctly, it would return true of the `child` is derived from `parent`. So I made a little checklist of which type combination should return `true` (in my opinion):

```
A: int, IComparable<int>
B: int, ValueType
C: int, object
D: List<int>, IList<int>
E: List<int>, IEnumerable<int>
F: List<int>, object

G: List<int>, List<>
H: List<int>, IList<>
I: List<>, IList<>
J: List<>, object
```

The given code fails at one point: Every time when the `parent` is of type `object`, false is returned. This is easily resolved by modifying your while-condition into:

```
while (currentChild != null)
```

Now to your `Blah`-function. What is does is check if the parent is a generic type definition. No 'normal' class (generic or not) can derive from a generic type definition. Only a generic type definition can derive from another generic type definition. So in order to let case G and H become true, a special converion has to be done. If the parent is a generic type definition AND when the child can be converted into a generic type definition, then the child will be converted into its generic type defintion.

That is all what it does.

So a perfect name for you function could be: `ConvertChildToGenericTypeDefinitionIfParentIsAGenericTypeDefinitionAndTheChildIsAGenericType(...)`

:)

Comment: Martin, I don't think you have answered my question. I know what individually those mean. What I don't understand is their relevance in the code. In other words, what purpose they are serving by having the `GetBlah` method. @Patashu has put it nicely in the comments, I think. To get `GetPossibleGenericTypeDefinition`, all I need to do is `child.IsGenericTypeDefinition ? child.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : child`, but there is `parent` argument in that method as well and its doing something there. I dont understand the relevance of that argument - which is what my question is about.