# Determining if type is a subclass of a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Check(new Foo());
        Check(new Bar());
    }
    static void Check<T>(T obj) {
        // "The type T cannot be used as type parameter..."
        if (typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Entity<T>))) {
            System.Console.WriteLine("obj is Entity<T>");
        }
    }
}
class Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>{ }
class Foo : Entity<Foo> { }
class Bar { }
```

What is the proper way to make this thing compile? I could subclass `Entity<T>` from a non generic `EntityBase` class, or could just try to `typeof(Entity<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T))` and see if it succeeds, but is there a way that doesn't abuse `try { } catch { }` blocks or mauls the type hierarchy?

There are some methods on `Type` that look like they could be useful, like `GetGenericArguments` and `GetGenericParameterConstraints` but I'm totally clueless as to how use them...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a class is derived from a generic class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class)

Comment: but I have no idea how to delete/close this question....

Comment: Actually, the answer given in the link that @MatthewWatson gave is better. Didn't see it until now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication4 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Check(new Foo());
            Check(new Bar());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void Check<T>(T obj) {
            // "The type T cannot be used as type parameter..."
            if (IsDerivedOfGenericType(typeof(T), typeof(Entity<>))) {
                System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} is Entity<T>", typeof(T)));
            }
        }

        static bool IsDerivedOfGenericType(Type type, Type genericType) {
            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
                return true;
            if (type.BaseType != null) {
                return IsDerivedOfGenericType(type.BaseType, genericType);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    class Entity<T> where T : Entity<T> { }
    class Foo : Entity<Foo> { }
    class Bar { }
}
```