# Compare without generics

Tags: c#

I have a bit complicated issue to solve.

I have a list of objects though later the list will be filled with two different type of instances.

First type is `MyFirstType<T1, T2>` and second type is `MySecondType<T>`

Now I need to run though the list of objects and ask which one of the two is each item. Then I need to do some custom logic on the item.

For example:

```
foreach(object obj in list)
{
   if(obj is MyFirstType<T1, T2>)
   {
     // do something
   }
   else if(obj is MySecondType<...>)
   {
   }
}
```

The problem is T or T1 and T2 could be any types so how do I write such an if - Is Keyword statement that only comparies if MyFirstType but not the generics inside? `if(obj is MyFirstType<T1, T2>)` does not work since it needs concrete types for T1 and T2.

Like mentioned just need comparison without T1 and T2. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/457676

Comment: This kind of type checking is almost always a product of taking the wrong approach to solve a problem; can you be a bit less abstract and detail what the actual task is and how you're trying to solve it?

Comment: @AntP Thanks but no thanks The question was not shall I change my design or not. It is clear enough what the problem is. If you cannot solve this please do not start discussion how could/should it have been done right.

Comment: @devhedgehog That is a pretty poor attitude but, sure, have it your way. I'm not going to waste my time helping you implement a sub-par solution, though I'm sure others will.

Comment: Yea right mr ant, please move on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IsGenericType` property of `Type` class to check if `obj.GetType()` is generic, and then use `GetGenericTypeDefinition` to get generic type definition, which can be compared to `typeof(MyFirstType<,>)` and `typeof(MySecondType<>)`:

```
foreach(object obj in list)
{
    if(obj.GetType().IsGenericType)
    {
        if(obj.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyFirstType<,>))
        {
          // do something
        }
        else if(obj.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MySecondType<>))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The cheap solution: create a flag interface which you derive in your types. This is just a helper to determine the type.
2. Use reflection and check the type definition and check the name of the type.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use polymorphism? Have the two types implement an interface with a common method. Then in the implementation of each type write the code for the method you need.

```
public interface ICommon
{
    void DoThis();
}
```

For MyFirstType and MySecondType you will have:

```
public class MyFirstType<T> : ICommon
{
    public void DoThis()
    {
        //DoThis
    }
}

public class MySecondType<T1,T2> : ICommon
{
    public void DoThis()
    {
        //DoThis
    }
}
```

Then you could write the following foreach loop:

```
foreach(object obj in list)
{
    obj.DoThis();
}
```

Comment: +1 for a good answer, though likely a wasted effort given comments.

Comment: I cannot change the types. They are third party. They are sealed. Thanks Ben anyway. I appreciate your suggestion. @AntP This is not a waisted efford however your comments are waisted efford. Havent you said you moved on?