# Fluent converters/mappers with Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, fluent

So, I got a bunch of classes I need to serialize/deserialize which also
happen to be domain objects (at least some of 'em), thus I want them to
be free of any attributes or not depending on a certain framework.

I looked at *Custom Converters* in Json.NET, but they look very '*ancient*' to me
in terms of usage and what not, since we nowadays have generics and it's not
that hard to implement a fluent interface. So before I'm going down the road of weak typing etc..

...what I'm looking for (pseudo):

```
public class MyModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SomeObj SomeObj { get; set; }
}

public class MyModelConverter : JsonConverter<MyModel> {

    public JsonConverter() {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).Name("Identifier");
        RuleFor(x => x.SomeObj).Name("Data")
            .WithConverter(new SomeObjConverter());
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).Ignore();
    }

}
```

Is there anything like that in Json.NET? Am I just missing something? (By the way I can't use different names for my properties etc. since the models are based on a 3rd party specification).

Comment: Maybe use `AutoMapper` and pour the domain object into the desired class? It has a syntax *ver* close to what you're looking for.

Comment: Extension methods and release your own enhancement plugin to shim JSON.NET!  :-)

Comment: You could simply create a new anonymous type and then serialize that.  `... new { Identifier = x.Id, ...}`

Answer (score 5):

Here is my take on achieving the desired API:

**Edited as per comment**

```
public abstract class Rule
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> rule { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    protected void AddRule(string key, object value)
    {
        if (rule.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            rule.Add(key, value);
        }
        else
        {
            rule[key] = value;
        }
    }

    protected IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> RegisteredRules
    {
        get
        {
            return rule.AsEnumerable();
        }
    }
}

public abstract class PropertyRule : Rule
{
    public MemberInfo PropertyInfo { get; protected set; }

    public void Update(JsonProperty contract)
    {
        var props = typeof(JsonProperty).GetProperties();
        foreach (var rule in RegisteredRules)
        {
            var property = props.Where(x => x.Name == rule.Key).FirstOrDefault();
            if (property != null)
            {
                var value = rule.Value;
                if (property.PropertyType == value.GetType())
                {
                    property.SetValue(contract, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class PropertyRule<TClass, TProp> : PropertyRule
{
    public const string CONVERTER_KEY = "Converter";
    public const string PROPERTY_NAME_KEY = "PropertyName";
    public const string IGNORED_KEY = "Ignored";

    public PropertyRule(Expression<Func<TClass, TProp>> prop)
    {
        PropertyInfo = (prop.Body as System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression).Member;
    }

    public PropertyRule<TClass, TProp> Converter(JsonConverter converter)
    {
        AddRule(CONVERTER_KEY, converter);
        return this;
    }

    public PropertyRule<TClass, TProp> Name(string propertyName)
    {
        AddRule(PROPERTY_NAME_KEY, propertyName);
        return this;
    }

    public PropertyRule<TClass, TProp> Ignore()
    {
        AddRule(IGNORED_KEY, true);
        return this;
    }
}

public interface SerializationSettings
{
    IEnumerable<Rule> Rules { get; }
}

public class SerializationSettings<T> : SerializationSettings
{
    private List<Rule> rules { get; } = new List<Rule>();

    public IEnumerable<Rule> Rules { get; private set; }

    public SerializationSettings()
    {
        Rules = rules.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public PropertyRule<T, TProp> RuleFor<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> prop)
    {
        var rule = new PropertyRule<T, TProp>(prop);
        rules.Add(rule);
        return rule;
    }
}

public class FluentContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    static List<SerializationSettings> settings;

    public static void SearchAssemblies(params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        SearchAssemblies((IEnumerable<Assembly>)assemblies);
    }

    public static void SearchAssemblies(IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies)
    {
        settings = assemblies.SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).Where(t => IsSubclassOfRawGeneric(t, typeof(SerializationSettings<>))).Select(t => (SerializationSettings)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToList();
    }

    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class
    static bool IsSubclassOfRawGeneric(System.Type toCheck, System.Type generic)
    {
        if (toCheck != generic)
        {
            while (toCheck != null && toCheck != typeof(object))
            {
                var cur = toCheck.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType ? toCheck.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : toCheck;
                if (generic == cur)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                toCheck = toCheck.GetTypeInfo().BaseType;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        var rule = settings.Where(x => x.GetType().GetTypeInfo().BaseType.GenericTypeArguments[0] == member.DeclaringType).SelectMany(x => x.Rules.Select(r => r as PropertyRule).Where(r => r != null && r.PropertyInfo.Name == member.Name)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (rule != null)
        {
            rule.Update(contract);
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Now in somewhere in program start-up:

```
FluentContractResolver.SearchAssemblies(typeof(MyModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => 
{
    return new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
        ContractResolver = new FluentContractResolver()
    };
};
```

With this in place you now just need to add classes with fluent settings:

```
public class MyModelSettings : SerializationSettings<MyModel> 
{

    public MyModelSettings() 
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).Name("Identifier");
        RuleFor(x => x.SomeObj).Name("Data").Converter(new SomeObjConverter());
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).Ignore();
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. The first line in PropertyRule.Update should be: 
     var props = typeof(JsonProperty).GetProperties();
2. For .NET Core the Type properties IsGenericType, Assembly, and BaseType are accessible via GetTypeInfo().
Appart from that everything else is okay. Nice solution.

Comment: @AlexanderChristov I have edited code as per your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Fluent-Json.NET](https://github.com/masbicudo/Fluent-Json.NET) allows you to map objects, use type discriminators, all without interfering with your data objects. No attributes are required.

**Mapping classes**

```
public class AnimalMap : JsonMap<Animal>
{
    public AnimalMap()
    {
        this.DiscriminateSubClassesOnField("class");
        this.Map(x => x.Speed, "speed");
    }
}

public class FelineMap : JsonSubclassMap<Feline>
{
    public FelineMap()
    {
        this.Map(x => x.SightRange, "sight");
    }
}

public class LionMap : JsonSubclassMap<Lion>
{
    public LionMap()
    {
        this.DiscriminatorValue("lion");
        this.Map(x => x.Strength, "strength");
    }
}
```

**Model classes**

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal(float speed)
    {
        this.Speed = speed;
    }

    public float Speed { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Feline : Animal
{
    protected Feline(float speed, float sightRange) : base(speed)
    {
        this.SightRange = sightRange;
    }

    public float SightRange { get; set; }
}

public class Lion : Feline
{
    public Lion(float speed, float sightRange, float strength) : base(speed, sightRange)
    {
        this.Strength = strength;
    }

    public float Strength { get; set; }
}
```