# C# - How to get the concrete type of base generic

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

Assuming I have a class A:

```
class A : B<C>, IA
{

}
```

And I also have a method like this:

```
Type GetConcreteB<T>() where T : IA
{
//some code here...
}
```

In this method I would like to check if `T` inherits from any `B` (currently I wrap `B` into an interface `IB` which does the thing) and if it does, return the concrete type of `C`.

So, basically I want to return the concrete type of the base generic class only using the subclass type. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a class is derived from a generic class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using reflection, go through the class hierarchy until you find a `B<T>`, and then extract the `T`:

```
static Type GetConcreteB<T>()
    where T : IA
{
    var t = typeof(T);
    while (t != null) {
        if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(B<>))
            return t.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        t = t.BaseType;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!