# Check if object is of generic type with multiple type arguments

Tags: c#, .net, class, generics, typeof

Assuming you have a Grid with an ItemsSource-Property (DataGrid.ItemsSource). This property is been set during runtime. A possible object could be the following:

```
public partial class InstantFeedbackCollectionViewModel<TEntity, TPrimaryKey, TUnitOfWork> 
   : InstantFeedbackCollectionViewModelBase<TEntity, TEntity, TPrimaryKey, TUnitOfWork>
```

Later during runtime I want to catch an Event and want to check whether the ItemsSource of the grid is of the type above.

Usually I would do something like that:

```
if (typeof(datagrid.ItemsSource) is InstantFeedbackCollectionViewModel) then ...
```

But how can I do this with this generic class?

UPDATE:

In the second step I would like to execute a method in the InstantFeedbackCollectionViewModel. Something like that:

```
if (datagrid.ItemsSource.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(InstantFeedbackCollectionViewModel<,,>) {
var instFeedbackCollectionViewModel = grid.ItemsSource;
instFeedbackCollectionViewModel.ExecuteMyMethod();
}
```

Does one know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know whether the type is a generic `InstantFeedbackCollectionViewModel` you can use this code :

```
bool isInstantFeedbackCollectionViewModel = 
      datagrid.ItemsSource.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
      typeof(InstantFeedbackCollectionViewModel<,,>);
```

If you want to know whether the type inherits from a generic `InstantFeedbackCollectionViewModel` then see [Check if a class is derived from a generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/457708/143503).

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted in the first step.

Comment: Yes. Do you have an idea to my additional question as well?

Comment: @SaschaR, define an interface IInstantFeedbackCollectionViewModel exposing the appropriate method. Implement it from InstantFeedbackCollectionViewModel<,,> then try to cast ItemSource as this interface.